# What is structure of lactose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image]
[image]
Please look at stereochemistry of anomeric carbon or carbon no.  1 of glucose unit. 
Which among two is correct structure of lactose?

If, both are correct, then how?

Note : Image 1 is from Harper biochemistry

Comment: Related  [How do we assign alpha/beta status in polysaccharides?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/how-do-we-assign-alpha-beta-status-in-polysaccharides)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of the images are lactose. The first image is $\alpha$-lactose and the second is $\beta$-lactose. The difference between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lactose is the orientation of the most right hydroxy (OH) group in the pictures.

Comment: Sorry, can you please focus on OH group at carbon 1..

Comment: When you say carbon 1, I assume you are refering to the carbon next the red "1". There is no OH group at this particular carbon. The four bonds to this carbons is  -O-, -O-, -C- and -H

Comment: Sorry again, anomeric carbon please.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel I edited my answer to include this difference

Comment: But both show beta glycosidic bonds?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel If I remember correctly what determines the difference between alpha and beta lactose is the form of the glucose. I.e. I think the galactose is always in beta form in lactose

Comment: Harper says lactose is O-α-D-galactopyranosyl-(1→4)-β-D-glucopyranose.